# How to open all video files with VLC

Tags: multimedia, vlc

I'm using VLC, which can open all kinds of files without problem, but how can I associate all video files (avi, mpg, wmv, flv, etc.) to be opened with VLC by default?

Comment: I removed the first sentence of your question about Banshee crashing, because I don't think it will affect the answer.  However, if you want to help make Banshee better, I'm sure the developers would appreciate it if you report that crash: http://banshee.fm/file-bugs

Answer (score 5):

You can right click at the desired video file then choose "Proprieties" > "Open with" the "VLC".

[image]

Also you can edit `mimeapps.list` at `~/.local/share/applications` and add:

```
video/dv=vlc.desktop;
video/mpeg=vlc.desktop;
video/x-mpeg=vlc.desktop;
video/msvideo=vlc.desktop;
video/quicktime=vlc.desktop;
video/x-anim=vlc.desktop;
video/x-avi=vlc.desktop;
video/x-ms-asf=vlc.desktop;
video/x-ms-wmv=vlc.desktop;
video/x-msvideo=vlc.desktop;
video/x-nsv=vlc.desktop;
video/x-flc=vlc.desktop;
video/x-fli=vlc.desktop;
application/ogg=vlc.desktop;
application/x-ogg=vlc.desktop;
application/x-matroska=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg=vlc.desktop;
audio/mpeg;audio/x-wav=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-mpegurl=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-scpls=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-m4a=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-ms-asf=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-ms-asx=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-ms-wax=vlc.desktop;
application/vnd.rn-realmedia=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-real-audio=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-pn-realaudio=vlc.desktop;
application/x-flac=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-flac=vlc.desktop;
application/x-shockwave-flash=vlc.desktop;
misc/ultravox;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-pn-wav=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-pn-windows-acm=vlc.desktop;
image/vnd.rn-realpix=vlc.desktop;
video/vnd.rn-realvideo=vlc.desktop;
audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin=vlc.desktop;
application/x-extension-mp4=vlc.desktop;
audio/mp4;video/mp4=vlc.desktop;
video/mp4v-es=vlc.desktop;
x-content/video-vcd=vlc.desktop;
x-content/video-svcd=vlc.desktop;
x-content/video-dvd=vlc.desktop;
x-content/audio-cdda=vlc.desktop;
x-content/audio-player=vlc.desktop;
video/x-flv=vlc.desktop;
```

Reference: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1674481).

Comment: I have to use at least 15 characters to say: welcome ;-)

Comment: @Julio please mark the answer as accepted, since it has provided the solution for you.