# Changing default software for opening video files not working - any ideas?

Tags: 12.04, vlc, default-programs, video-player

I used the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158547/how-do-i-change-default-program-to-open-video-files-12-04) to change the default software for opening video files to VLC player on Ubuntu 12.04. The settings **say** that this is now the default player and yet whenever I play the files they are still opening with Movie Player. Is there anything I can do to fix this or must I uninstall Movie Player ????

Comment: What happens if you right click on the file and choose open with vlc?

Comment: It plays, but that is not what I consider default really. I thought default would just play it in VLC on double click

Comment: Try to right click on the file, choose properties, open with, and click on set default button, and see if it works.

Comment: For formats like avi, mp4, flv , etc you need to specify once by right clicking it to open with VLC with each available Video Format you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click on a file, go to the last entry (Properties) and select in the new window the 'Open with' tab.

There you see the standard-application, the recommended app and other apps for opening this file.

In the list of other applications, you can select which application to use for opening the movie. (VLC media player)

Now the file should be opened by VLC.

Answer (score 1):

A more global solution. 
The file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` has the bindings of the file extension v/s application to use for that extension.

for the video types you need jus replace the current entry for exmaple 
*video/3gpp=totem.desktop* to *video/3gpp=vlc.desktop*.